# Trigger multiple selection on long click

Tags: android, listview, multipleselection, long-click

I'm building a File manager on android platform.I want my users to be able to select multiple files on long click on a file.How to do it?(In list view)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: when user long clicks on a file.The list view mode should change to multiple so that user is able to select multiple files.

Comment: `lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long id) {
               // I want to add something over here to change previous mode of list view to MULTIPLE selection mode

                return true;
            }
        }); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using a `ListView`, I believe you're looking for `android:choiceMode="multipleChoiceModal"` or `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL)`