# Android open ListView for multiple selection programmatically

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I got a fragment with a `ListView`. The purpose of the list is simply checking items in that list, so I want to add something to the `onCreateView` method which will make the list enter its multiple selection mode automatically as the fragment shows, without the need for the user to long press an item. How can I do that?

Comment: onCreateview() just show multiple selection listiview instead of simple listview if there is no more purpose than this. @JJ Ab

Comment: OK and that is exactly the question - how? I know how to set it for multiple selection but it is only triggered by a long click. How do I trigger it programatically?

Answer (score 0):

to use longpress , you can do this way,

```
android:choiceMode="multipleChoiceModal" 
or
setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL)
```

go through this for more [information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29474849/2826147)

Comment: You got it wrong. A ListView in Android can be set to a multiple selection mode. After doing so, the list enters this mode when a user is long clicking a list item. I am not asking how to do something when long clicking. I'm asking how to enter the multiple selection mode WITHOUT the need for a long click.

Comment: Again you got it wrong. Your edit only shows me how to set the list so when a user long click it, it will enter a multiple selection mode. I'm asking how to enter that multiple selection mode programatically WITHOUT LONG PRESS. NOT with. Without.

Comment: sounds more like what I want but the answer is not something that is logical to do. its a very bad hacking.. that answer is from 2013. maybe there were some changes since then?